# Flask app hangs for multiple users from long query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I deployed the app with uWSGI like so:

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app --enable-threads --lazy
```

I have a route in my app that takes a while to run (SQLAlchemy query), and causes other users to not be able to connect.

What can I do about this?

Comment: increase the number of workers? http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Cheaper.html

Comment: This may solve the problem for now, but isn't there a decent overhead at just launching more workers? I am considering adding a task queue down the line.

Comment: True, there can only be so many workers as your server's RAM allows, and you will end up with pretty much the same situation you are in now once more users come. One thing to do would be to break down that task so that each task takes only so much of RAM. The other is of course a task queue